# Disable_error_and_usage_SQLserver

Tags: sql-server, error-reporting

Q: How disable ,Microsoft SQL server Error and usage data reporting?

Microsoft:

> By default, Microsoft SQL Server collects information about how its
>   customers are using the application. Specifically, SQL Server collects
>   information about the installation experience, usage, and performance.
>   This information helps Microsoft improve the product to better meet
>   customer needs. For example, Microsoft collects information about what
>   kinds of error codes customers encounter so that we can fix related
>   bugs, improve our documentation about how to use SQL Server, and
>   determine whether features should be added to the product to better
>   serve customers.

I know we can turnoff send any report to Microsoft by Unchecked 2 item , from **SQL server Error and usage data reporting** (start menu > search and open error and usage reporting )

[image: disabled image(default is enable)]

I need help me about other way, But, I need disable this option by (DML.comannd like Script or Batch-file or cmd-prompt or Other automatically way or app control way), because I'm admin for 1249 server in Various areas in country.

Comment: This is Microsoft article about it, it mentions setting registry keys, amongst other things: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/usage-and-diagnostic-data-configuration-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Alex how to set .bat file... i try do it but, not work well.